# Matar proceso desconocido en Linux

Tags: linux

Hola hay un proceso que antes no aparecía y ahora aparece, y desde allí el servidor se ha puesto lento.
Adjunto imagen.
[image: Listado de procesos de mi servidor]
Me gustaría que alguien me diga si se trata de un virus o cuál puede ser la razón.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda. El otro proceso que se encuentra debajo, también desconozco de qué sea.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que normalmente corre en el servidor que tu sepas que se haya instalado o implementado?

Comment: Trata de averiguar el nombre y ubicación exacta del proceso con `top -c` o mucho mejor `ps aux`. Y comparte las salidas en forma de texto no de imagen.

Comment: En ese servidor corre el apache2 hace meses

Comment: Yo primero miraría con ps -c y guardaría el resultado. Busca qué proceso lo arranca con un ps -ef |grep 7237. Lo mataría y haría un find / -name "*!!*" para saber si está en mas sitios. No está de mas hacer un find $HOMEwwwrun/ -exec -grep "!!" {} \; para ver si algo lo arranca, revisaría los permisos del apache por si estuviera el permiso de escritura en algún subdirectorio. Cuando lo encuentres, mira la fecha y revisa los logs, para saber desde donde lo han metido. Si encuentras una ip, búscala si está en alguna blacklist

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es sobre dearrollo